# How to specify file format of Split Vector Layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, convert, geopackage

I'm attempting to use the Split Vector Layer tool in QGIS (see screenshot below) in order to separate a larger shapefile into its constituent components by object ID. The tool accomplishes this perfectly, but by default exports everything as a geopackage file.

[image]

I instead require these files as shapefiles, not geopackage files. Is there any way to specify within QGIS that I want to export these files as such?

Comment: Looks like this will not be fixed anytime soon either.  https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/29522

Comment: The workaround is to export it as a temporary file, then save the temporary file in the format you want.